# What are the different tests in R you can use to compare the proportions of two binomial-distributed populations?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

What are the different tests you can use to compare two binomially-distributed populations in R?

I have two populations (`n1` and `n2`) with successes (`x1` and `x2`). Given the following cases, what kind of tests should I use for the different cases?

1. Small `x1`&`x2`, large `n1`&`n2`
2. Large `x1`&`x2`, large `n1`&`n2`
3. Small `x1`or`x2`, large `n1`&`n2`
4. Large `x1`or`x2`, large `n1`&`n2`

I am aware of functions like `prop.test`, `binom.test` and `fisher.test`, but I am not too sure which one to choose.

Additionally, say I have a continuous variable, `X`. I create 3 binary splits for them so that we have Group 1: `X<10`, Group 2: `X>=10 & X<20` and Group 3: `X>=20`. Hence, the following is my counts and proportions.

**Population 1**

```
                 Total         X<10   X>=10 & X<20       X>=20
No. of Successes   300            4            200          50
Proportion           -   0.01333333      0.6666667   0.1666667
```

**Population 2**

```
                 Total         X<10   X>=10 & X<20       X>=20
No. of Successes   700           10            500         100
Proportion           -   0.01428571      0.7142857   0.1428571
```

Would it be okay if I use `fisher.test` for the first group to compare population 1 and population 2 and `prop.test` for group 2 and group 3. Or should I standardise and use `fisher.test` for all?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?  Whether the probabilities are the same?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I want to test for equality of proportions.

Comment: For cases 3 and 4, where your `n1` and `n2` are both large, but only one of `x1` or `x2` is large, then you can use common sense and conclude that the proportions are not equal.

Comment: @Gregor yes, but if you want to do research, you need to report the p-values. You can't just say, by common sense.